# FragmentActivity: proper fragment instantiation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I have a `FragmentActivity` and two `Fragment`s, say `FrgMaster` (a `ListFragment`) and `FrgDetail`. I have two layout XML files: one containing a single `FrameLayout` (for portrait mode) and one containing two `FrameLayout`s (for landscape). I want to instantiate the fragments in my `FragmentActivity` so in `onCreate()` I have something like:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    final FrgMaster fragment = new FrgMaster();
    // Add the fragment to the FrameLayout
    this.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frame_for_master, fragment, FrgMaster.MY_TAG)
            .commit();
}
```

I browse the list and click in places. Now, when I change orientation, the code above does not work, since `savedInstanceState` is not `null`; therefore the fragment is not added to the layout. If I remove the the `if` condition, I end up with multiple fragments, one for each orientation change, stacked.

What am I missing?

Comment: "Now, when I change orientation, the code above does not work, since savedInstanceState is not null; therefore the fragment is not added to the layout" -- it should be re-added to the layout automatically as part of normal configuration-change processing. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/LargeScreen/EU4You

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You propose another approach? This is something I shouldn't do?

Comment: No, it's more that what you have probably should work, though I tend to use what Corey Scott has in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its unclear whether you are including the link to the fragment in the layout file or not.
If you are then you don't need the beginTransacton().add(x).commit() part at all.

Assuming you are not adding the fragments in XML and only in code you might get some mileage out of changing your code to the following:

```
FragmentManager manager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
FrmMaster fragment = manager.findFragmentById(FrgMaster.MY_TAG);
if (fragment == null)
{
    manager
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.frame_for_master, fragment, FrgMaster.MY_TAG)
        .commit();
}
```

EDIT: Changed syntax to follow OP's style

Comment: Your syntax is slightly off on the transaction -- `add()` and `commit()` would be chained off of `beginTransaction()`, as it's a fluent interface. That being said, your intention is spot-on.

Comment: This is right. @denispyr: Or you can use this to prevent your activity from being recreated after screen orientation changed: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|keyboard"` (set it to your `<activity>` element in `AndroidManifest.xml`).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the input, I changed it to the OP's style.  For me I prefer the other style, is there any reason to use one or the other? or is it just personal preference?

Comment: I tried your proposal (difference: manager.findFragmentByTag) and the fragment is not null when I rotate the device.

Comment: @CoreyScott: Since there is neither an `add()` nor a `commit()` method on `FragmentManager`, I fail to see how your original source would compile.

Comment: I tried to add `setRetainInstance(false)` in `FrgMAster` s `onActivityCreated` but it didn't help. The `manager.findFragmentById(FrgMaster.MY_TAG)` is not null as soon as `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` gets called with a non null `savedInstanceState` (which was my original problem).

Comment: @CommonsWare you are totally right, thats what I get for posting code without checking it properly first

Comment: @denispyr can we infer from your comments/code that you are trying to restore the state of the fragments on when the code is run the second time?  if so, have you considered using the reference to fragment to pass the new state?

Comment: My mistake was that I added the `Fragment` to a container named `foo` when portrait, `bar` when landscape. That gave me all kind of problems. Thx for helping me clarify the code.